# Creating a horizontal gradient on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Ok I can do a vertical gradient on a UITableViewCell doing this on its class:

```
  UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];

  CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
  gradient.frame = self.bounds;

  gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor],
                       (id)[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor], nil];

  [backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:1];

  [self setBackgroundView:backgroundView];
```

but what about a **horizontal** gradient, from left to right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple documentation checking:

`CAGradientLayer` has a `startPoint` and `endPoint` property. I assume you can use these to  position the gradient.